# Access value in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this object:

```
var myValues = {
  55bdf7bda89de40349854077: ["hello"]
  55be0c77a89de403498540bc: ["goodbye"]
  55be0e22a89de403498540c1: ["hey there!"]
}
```

And a variable as contains an id:

```
var id = '55be0e22a89de403498540c1';
```

I want to find in the object by this id and get the value in array.

I try to find with:

```
myValues.id[0]
```

but ... not works ;/

Anybody can help me?

Comment: `myValues[id][0]`

Comment: Thanks!! it works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `myValues[id]` or `myValues['55be0e22a89de403498540c1']`. It's a json object, not a primitive array so you can't access it with indexes like you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks you so much! it works and finally understand why not works :)

Answer (score 1):

Your array should like,

```js
var myValues = {
  '55bdf7bda89de40349854077': "hello",
  '55be0c77a89de403498540bc': "goodbye",
  '55be0e22a89de403498540c1': "hey there!"
}

alert(myValues["55be0e22a89de403498540c1"])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

May this will help you

Comment: Thanks!! you've help me a lot with the snippet